# How do I set the owner of a registry key using powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, permissions, windows-registry, ownership

I'm trying to modify the permissions of a registry key, however before I can do that I need to change the owner of that key.

Is it possible to do that using a powershell script? I've seen that you can modify the permissions of any group using RegistryAccessRules but I couldn't find any info about changing the owner of that key.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does [How do I take ownership of a registry key via PowerShell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044432/how-do-i-take-ownership-of-a-registry-key-via-powershell) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not really, after using the enable-privilege function: 
enable-privilege(SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege)

and trying to set $key to this value:
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsRuntime\AllowedCOMCLSIDs\",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::takeownership)


I get "access to the registry key is denied" error so can't really follow with the rest of the script. What am I missing here?

Comment: admin elevate the shell then run the logic and see what happens. Also, see my answer on this post if there is a multistring, you have to rebuild it with array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009154/create-symlink-with-gpo/68582226#68582226